# Fetch pagination number from infinite scroll using GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager

Our engineers added page_number datalayer for search_impression event, so while the user its scrolling down the results the page_number got printed, but the tag is not firing, cannot tell if there is change made or not. I added history pushstate trigger but still the tag wont fire with infinite scroll page. What trigger to use to fire the event for infinite scroll page?
your help would be highly appreciated. thank you